# Qt application freezes when accessing QList<QLlnkedList<QUrl>* > from NetworkAccessManager->get() callback

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qlist, qlinkedlist

My application freezes when I am trying to access a `QList<QLinkedList<QUrl>* >` within the `replyFinished(QNetworkReply* networkReply);` slot of a `QNetworkAccessManager`.

I basically loop once over the list add something to the list and then exit the function:

```
foreach (QLinkedList<QUrl>* list, mList) {
    if (list->front() == url) {
        list->prepend(someUrl);
        mNetworkAccessManager->get(someUrl);
        return; 
    }
}
```

In the other scenario I do the following:

```
QList<QLinkedList<QUrl>* >::iterator it = mList.begin();
while (it != mList.end()) {
    QLinkedList<QUrl>* list = *it;
    if (list->front() == networkReply->url()) {
        // some operation with list->back();
        mList.erase(it);
        delete list;
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make this construct safe?

Comment: That list of pointers to linked lists of urls seems quite horrendous. I got one word for you - DEBUG.

Comment: Yes, don't use pointers

Comment: Even if I don't use a pointer, my application crashes. I think the reason is that the slot `replyFinished` gets called multiple times and `QList` and `QLinkedList` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was caught in an endless loop, since

```
QList<QLinkedList<QUrl>* >::iterator it = mList.begin();
while (it != mList.end()) {
    QLinkedList<QUrl>* list = *it;
```

never increased the iterator ..